# Linearly "smoothed" function using lookup table

Tags: java, data-structures

If I want to write a function (probably also a class) which returns linearly "smoothed" data from an immutable lookup table (fixed when calling constructor) like this:
[image: An example of lookup table and results]

For example `func(5.0) == 0.5`.

---

1. What is the best way of storing the lookup table?

   - I am thinking of using two arrays.
   - Could there be other better ways?
2. What is the best way of calculating the required value? (In terms of real-time efficiency, excluding preparation time)

   - I am thinking of pre-sorting the lookup table on `arg` and using a binary search to find the nearest two points.
   - Or should I build a binary tree to simplify searching?
   - Or could there be other better ways?
3. *(Minor)* What would one call this kind of function/class/data-structure/algorithms? Is there any formal names for this in Computer Science?

I think I may need to write my own class. The class, at best, should be immutable because there is no need to change it after initialization and probably multiple threads will be using it. I may also need to get keys and values by the index.

Comment: What's the precision of the argument to `func()`? You can consider storing pre-calculated values.

Comment: @XiaoJia Double preceision? Seriously I think pre-calculating the value *could* work for *some* situations, I can round the input to integer value. I could make another implementation, but different from this. I still need another implementation that calculates the value real-time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to linearly interpolate a set of points. I'd use  `java.util.NavigableMap`. It provides functions such as `higherEntry(K key)` and `lowerEntry(K key)` which facilitates getting the neighboring points.

You put into the map your `(x,y)`s. When queried for `f(x_i)`, you'd first check if the mapping is contained in your map, if it is, return it. If not you'd call `higherKey(x_i)` and `lowerKey(x_i)` to find the neighboring two points. Then use the formula to interpolate those two points (see
[Wikipedia's Linear Interpolation Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)).

I'd also implement the interpolation logic in a different class, and pass it in as a constructor argument to your `function` class in case you want to use different interpolation methods (i.e. polynomial interpolation) later.

Comment: So it will search three times? I am not sure of the implementation of `NavigableMap` but if I implement my own and use one single binary search I can catch the two points or the dedicated value in one iteration. Probably three times faster... anyway +1 for "interpolation logic in different class".

Comment: Yea I think `TreeMap`, will search twice if you call `higherEntry` and `lowerEntry` but your overall running time would still be `2log n = O(log n)`. I guess the question here is whether you want to spend time implementing your own data structure and (modified) binary search or use an existing implementation with a small penalty. Just curious, how big will your data set be? Is it actually worth the development time? Logarithmic runtime scales pretty well.

Comment: The dataset would at most be 300 points. For most cases using existing implementations is a good idea, but I think I may need some kind of `getKeyAt` and `getValueAt`. I would also want the class to be immutable.

Comment: Create an immutable class (i.e. `InterpolatedFunction`)and use `NavigableMap` internally to manage the points. Make sure the map doesn't leak out of the composing class. Now any client using `InterpolatedFunction` will have read-only access to the data set.